# Which function to use for swapping eth against token on uniswap?

Tags: solidity, ether, uniswap, python

I use the following code to create the swap_transaction:

```
swap_transaction = router_contract.functions.swapETHForExactTokens(
        0, [weth_address  ,token_address], account_address, int(time.time()) + (10000)

    ).build_transaction(

        {
            'nonce': nonce,
            'gas': 200000,
            'gasPrice': w3.to_wei(gasprice,'gwei'),
            'from': account_address,
            'value': w3.to_wei(ether_amount,'ether')

        }
    )
```

Here I use the swapETHForExactTokens function but I have also seen the 'swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens' function. What is the difference between these two and which one should I use? In tutorials and the unofficial uniswap python package the 'swapETHForExactTokens' is used but when I go to etherscan I also see the other function. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are some tokens that charge a fee for every transfer. A new function was introduced `swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` because the original function `swapExactETHForTokens` doesn't know how to deal with those type of tokens.

From the developer [documentation](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#swapexacttokensfortokenssupportingfeeontransfertokens)

> `swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`:
> Identical to `swapExactTokensForTokens`, but succeeds for tokens that take a fee on transfer.